# Parse a Json in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I have a problem to parse a Json file.
try to parse a Json file:

```
{
  "id": 1234,
  "lists": {
    "pause": {
      "attached": [
        {
          "from": 1576680044000,
          "to": 1576680055000,
          "length": 11000
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "time": {
    "start_time": 1576680044000,
    "end_time": 1576680055000
  }
}
```

Here are the two structs that I defined for it.

Pause struct:

```
public struct Pause: Decodable {

   public let attached: [AttachedModel]

   init(badlAttached: [AttachedModel] = []) {
      self.attached = attached
   }

   private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case attached = "attached"
   }
}
```

AttachedModel model struct:

```
public struct AttachedModel: Decodable {

   private enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
      case from, to
   }

   public let range: Range<Int64>

   init(range: Range<Int64>) {
      self.range = range
   }

   public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      do {
         let rootContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
         let from: Int64 = try rootContainer.decode(key: .from)
         let to: Int64 = try rootContainer.decode(key: .to)
         range = from ..< to
      } catch {
         throw JSONDecoder.DecodingError(type: type(of: self), payload: error)
      }
   }
}
```

Then, I create a key for it and a function:

```
   enum Key: String {
      case lists
      case pause = "pause"
   }

 func pause() throws -> Pause? {
      let seriesJSON = try lists()
      if let json = seriesJSON[Key.pause.rawValue] as? [String: Any] {
         return try JSONDecoder().decode(Pause.self, from: json) //It's never called
      } else {
         return nil
      }
   }
```

in function `lists()`:

```
func lists() throws -> [String: Any] {
      let json: [String: Any] = try payload.valueForRequiredKey(Key. lists.rawValue)
      return json
   }
```

Here is the output of the `list()`

```
  [1] = {
    key = "pause"
    value = {
      payload_data_0 = 0x0000600001af8a10 {
        ObjectiveC.NSObject = {
          baseNSObject@0 = {
            isa = __NSSingleObjectArrayI
          }
        }
      }
      payload_data_1 = 0x544e786f6a497768
      payload_data_2 = 0x444f3363544e3363
      instance_type = 0x00007fe02f877ed0
    }
  }
```

The problem is, even when `pause` has data, this line is always false `if let json = seriesJSON[Key.pause.rawValue] as? [String: Any] {` and it goes to `nil`
Could anyone tell me where is the problem here?

Comment: What is `let seriesJSON = try lists()` and why are you trying to decode a dictionary?

Comment: I updated the first post for `list()`, It pars the Json, then I want to get data from "pause" key in the next step

Comment: If `json` is a dictionary then why decode it as JSON?

Comment: how it should be? it's a old project and I try to fix it

Comment: I didn't ask that, I asked why you did the cast to a dictionary? Since the decoding is never called it is clear that the cast fails. I think you need to investigate what type `payload` is and what kind of data it contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create this as model class for you json:

```
import Foundation

class MyItem: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let lists: Lists
    let time: Time
}

class Lists: Codable {
    let pause: Pause
}

class Pause: Codable {
    let attached: [Attached]
}

class Attached: Codable {
    let from, to, length: Int
}

class Time: Codable {
    let start_time, end_time: Int
}

// MARK: - Helper functions for creating encoders and decoders
fileprivate func newJSONDecoder() -> JSONDecoder {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    if #available(iOS 10.0, OSX 10.12, tvOS 10.0, watchOS 3.0, *) {
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
    }
    return decoder
}

fileprivate func newJSONEncoder() -> JSONEncoder {
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    if #available(iOS 10.0, OSX 10.12, tvOS 10.0, watchOS 3.0, *) {
        encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .iso8601
    }
    return encoder
}
```

Then you can parse it like this:

```
let myItem = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(MyItem.self, from: jsonData)
// Read from (for example)
let from = myItem.lists.pause.attached[0].from
```

Comment: thanks, may I ask what is the problem with that code that I shared?

Comment: Yes, first the json is not consistent you have "length" and "len" i think it's a typo, no?
can you add the full json (it's starts with "pause" now and ends with ],)

Comment: Yes I wrote it wrong here. 
I added the full Json in the first post. And for another parts of project, I have to keep this structure, could you please tell me how to fix the code with the same structure?

Comment: You don't need classes and you can delete all `init` methods.

Comment: Dear @vadian please look at the second post

Comment: @Pual What is `payload`? What is `valueForRequiredKey`? Why don't you use light-weight and efficient `Codable`?

Comment: Dear @Pual please recheck my edited answer. it's the correct way to parse json in swift, using codable

Comment: @R.A. When copying code from QuickType.io you need to either copy _all_ code or edit it. There is no such thing as `newJSONDecoder()` in swift, it is created by QuickType.io. Also `try?` is not a good practice for error handling