# Connect the data as dictionary to the model

Tags: json, swift, nsdictionary

I get the data from the server and keep them in a dictionary, the Json data looks like that:

```
{
  "id": 1234,
  "lists": {
    "pause": {
      "attached": [
        {
          "from": 1576680044000,
          "to": 1576680055000,
          "length": 11000
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "time": {
    "start_time": 1576680044000,
    "end_time": 1576680055000
  }
 }
}
```

I read this data and keep them in a dictionary, this is the output of the dictionary:

```
   ([[String : Any]]?) $R18 = 1 value {
  [0] = 1 key/value pair {
    [0] = {
      key = "attached"
      value = {
        payload_data_0 = 0x0000600002d51b30 3 elements {
          [0] = 0x00006000036d2b80 3 key/value pairs
          [1] = 0x00006000036d32c0 3 key/value pairs
          [2] = 0x00006000036d2400 3 key/value pairs
        }
        payload_data_1 = 0x2f73746375646f72
        payload_data_2 = 0x70692d6775626544
        instance_type = 0x00007fd61984ab70
      }
    }
  }
```

Now, I want to connect this data to the models

here is Pause model:

```
public struct Pause: Decodable {

   public let attached: [AttachedModel]

   init(attached: [AttachedModel] = []) {
      attached = attached
   }

   private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case attached = "attached"
   }
}
```

and attachedModel model:

```
public struct AttachedModel: Decodable {

   private enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
      case from, to, len
   }

   public let range: Range<Int64>

   init(range: Range<Int64>) {
      self.range = range
   }

   public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      do {
         let rootContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
         let from: Int64 = try rootContainer.decode(key: .from)
         let to: Int64 = try rootContainer.decode(key: .to)
         range = from ..< to
      } catch {
         throw JSONDecoder.DecodingError(type: type(of: self), payload: error)
      }
   }
}
```

In the networking part (socket), I create a function for this:

```
func pause() throws -> Pause? {
      let lists = try lists()
      if let data = lists["pause"] as? [[String : Any]] {
         return JSONDecoder().decode(Pause.self, from: data)
         //The old form of this return, I think it's wrong and now it shows this error: Cannot invoke 'decode' with an argument list of type '(Pause.Type, from: [[String : Any]])'
      } else {
         return nil
      }
```

As I said, the `data` holds the dictionary of the data; Here is the output of the data:

```
 ([[String : Any]]?) $R18 = 1 value {
  [0] = 1 key/value pair {
    [0] = {
      key = "attached"
      value = {
        payload_data_0 = 0x0000600002d51b30 3 elements {
          [0] = 0x00006000036d2b80 3 key/value pairs
          [1] = 0x00006000036d32c0 3 key/value pairs
          [2] = 0x00006000036d2400 3 key/value pairs
        }
        payload_data_1 = 0x2f73746375646f72
        payload_data_2 = 0x70692d6775626544
        instance_type = 0x00007fd61984ab70
      }
    }
  }
```

Please look at the comment below the return, I added the firm that it was before, but it's wrong now and also it shows an error, could anyone help me how connect this data to those model?
Thanks

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Rather than reposting the same question [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59515258/parse-a-json-in-swift) and [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59516426/type-of-json-data-to-pars) show the entire relevant code you are using, the expected result and the error you're getting. Once again: You have to parse the JSON always from the top of the object.

Comment: Dear @vadian, I am really sorry about that. Could you look at PGDev post, it seems a good way in my case without change many things in the model, but I have a problem there (see the next comment if the answer), you could please help me on that,

Answer (score 0):

In case you only want to fetch `attached` data from the above JSON, you can create the models like,

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let attached: [Attached]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case lists, pause, attached
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let pause = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self).nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .lists).nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .pause)
        self.attached = try pause.decode([Attached].self, forKey: .attached)
    }
}

struct Attached: Decodable {
    let to: Int64
    let from: Int64
    var range: Range<Int64> {
        return from..<to
    }
}
```

Now, parse the data using

```
do {
    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(response.attached)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

**Edit:**

Valid *JSON*,

```
{
  "id": 1234,
  "lists": {
    "pause": {
      "attached": [
        {
          "from": 1576680044000,
          "to": 1576680055000,
          "length": 11000
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "time": {
    "start_time": 1576680044000,
    "end_time": 1576680055000
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try this way and I hope it works. Thanks again

Comment: It can't decode it, the error that it prints is `(DecodingError) $R0 = <invalid> (0x18)`. Somehow the problem comes from this line `let pause = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self).nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .lists).nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .pause)`

Comment: That just fetches the pause container from the JSON. And it is working at my end. Can you please show how you're doing it.

Comment: Also, the JSON you added in the question is not valid. I've added the valid JSON in the answer. Do refer that.

Answer (score 0):

try change `if let data = lists["pause"] as? [[String : Any]]` to `if let data = lists["pause"] as? [String : AnyObject]`. After that you should convert to the data and from the data to the expected model. I did not change your model and everything worked correctly.

```
if let jsonPart = value?["pause"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
    if let dataFromJSON = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonPart, options: .prettyPrinted) {
        let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Pause.self, from: dataFromJSON)
        print(result)
    }
}
```

**upd.**

I've added your JSON into file and read from bundle like here:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "file", ofType: "json") {
    do {
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
        if let jsonResult = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as? [String: AnyObject]  {
            let value = jsonResult["lists"]
            if let data = value?["pause"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                if let dataFromJSON = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: .prettyPrinted) {
                    let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Pause.self, from: dataFromJSON)
                    print(result) //here your object, not nil
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, because it's not my project, I prefer to don't change the model as you said. I tried your way, `[String : AnyObject]` made the `dataFromJSON` nil. The only way that It won't be nil is using `[[String : Any]]`

Comment: @Pual I've updated my answer, because it is very strange that you have nil. I have a correct object

Comment: Dear Vadim, thank you so much for your help. the first if `if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "file", ofType: "json") {` is failed. I start to work in this complicated project that is why I don't know many things about other part of this project. If you can somehow tell me if I use `[[String : Any]]` how can I manage the result *return). because when I use `[[String : Any]]`, it wont be nil